# Как найти по имени нужный файл и вывести из него значения?

Tags: php

На странице `site.ru/us/page.php` у меня есть переменная `$file[8]`, которая выводит `id` пользователя - это число, состоящее из десяти цифр (1234567890).

В папке `site.ru/us/db/us/` лежат файлы (не txt, а просто файлы без расширения) с данными пользователей, имеют такой вид:
site.ru/us/db/us/1234567890
site.ru/us/db/us/2564895456
site.ru/us/db/us/2548566237
и т.д.
Где имена файлов - это `id` пользователей.

**Вопрос:** как по `id`, который выводит переменная `$file[8]`, найти нужный файл в этой папке с именем, совпадающим с этим `id`, чтобы на странице `page.php` из найденного файла можно было выводить значения (строки) с помощью переменных `$user[1]`, `$user[2]`, `$user[3]` и т.д.?

**Моя неудачная попытка:**

```
$dir = __DIR__ . 'us/db/us';
$user_name1 = array();
foreach(glob($dir . $file[8], GLOB_BRACE) as $file[8]) {

    $user_name1 = basename($file[8]);
}
```

Comment: *"Моя неудачная попытка"* ---  это абстрактное описание, всё равно что прийти к врачу и сказать "у меня в теле болит".... где болит, какие боли, как часто, какой интенсивности....видимо надо клещами вытаскивать

Comment: `as $file[8]` --- это какая-то странность..... зачем так делать и вообще понимаете что написали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть путь до файлов виде `$dir` и есть айдишник в виде `$file[8]`, то магическим образом это и есть путь до файла. Зачем что-то пытаться искать?

```
$data = file_get_contents($dir . '/' . $file[8]);
```

А дальше, что нужно делать с содержимым переменной `$data`, то и делайте